# How to get obstacle distance and angle by using lidar

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how to get obstacle distance and angle from mobile robot by using lidar?

I have a small mobile robot  with a Lidar A1M8..
I would like to process the data coming from the liar raw data  `\scan` or from `gmapping` package, to use this data to make a path planning algorithm like "Genetic Algorithm".
So, I do not want to use move_base package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370071/how-to-get-obstacle-distance-and-angle-by-using-lidar/) by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have a ROS driver for the laser scanner on your robot, then you should also have laser scan messages published on a specific topic name.
Find out the topic and then look for the message type.
Normally planar laser scans are published using the `LaserScan` message which is defined in the `sensor_msgs` package.
See here:

[sensor_msgs/LaserScan Message](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html)

You will see that the message *does not* contain the angle of each measurement, but the **start angle** of the scan and the **angle increment**.

Taking everything into account, these are the main steps to get the **distance** and **angle** for each ray in a  `LaserScan` message:

- Create a ros node that subscribes to your laser scanner topic
- Specify a callback function to run when the subscriber receives a message
- Upon incoming messages, iterate over all laser rays
- Skip laser rays with the value 'inf' (rays that didn't hit anything)
- To have your measurements in polar coordinates (distance and angle w.r.t. your device):

Use the fields `angle_min`, the start angle of the scan [rad] and `angle_increment`, the angular distance between measurements [rad], to get each's ray angle, like this:
`ray_angle = angle_min + (i * angle_increment)` , where `i` is the loop counter that change with each iteration of the loop

Get the distance of the corresponding ray from the data field `ranges[i]`

This is how to find the position of a detected obstacle in polar coordinates in the reference frame of your sensor.
Most probably you will also want to transform these values to get cartesian coordinates from polar ones.
Also consider if you want to transform these into the global frame or not.

---

Originally posted by [Roberto Z.](https://answers.ros.org/users/39640/roberto-z./) with karma: 500 on 2021-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Roberto Z.](https://answers.ros.org/users/39640/roberto-z./) on 2021-03-15**:
@Ahmed_Desoky did this answer your question?

**Comment by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on 2022-03-01**:
Thanks a lot. This is the answer.

**Comment by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on 2022-07-13**:
@Roberto Z.  Why do not you use the `angle_max` ? Why do you use only the `angle_min`?